# How to add correct key:value pair to Xcode info.plist

Tags: xcode

I am trying to add an info string and description for NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription  as the error describes below. However, I have never used Xcode before, and apparently how I adding the key and value are incorrect. The key is setting to default item 1 so I have to put NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription  in the value. so obviously its not working. What is the workaround in this case?

```
ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data.
```

[image: info.plist from project]

Comment: did you save, clear build and run?

Answer (score 1):

Same issue today for me.
It's not the first time that Apple send us that issue after uploading build.

It looks like their automated checks fails sometimes.
Last time we've waited few hours and submitted again a new build (same source code) and it worked.

[EDIT]
Following https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/680170 it seems that Apple changed their checking rules. We have InfoPlist.strings file in our Watch extension and builds were processed in the past. Now it requires missing keys to be in the Info.plist alongside any localisation file to complete processing builds.